# output printer ESC codes from twig in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, printing, twig

I have a system that uses Symfony, and is connected to a (citizen ct-s2000) POS printer.

What I currently do is render the string to send to the printer, using the twig service:

```
$this->templatingService->render('SamPosBundle:Ticket:template1.html.twig', array('order' => $order))
```

and send this to the printer using fwrite, after that I feed the paper 1 line and cut the paper using:

```
fwrite($handle, chr(hexdec('0A')));
fwrite($handle, chr(hexdec('1B')).chr(hexdec('69')));
```

This all works like a charm, however.

Now I am looking for a way to send the escape codes from WITHIN the twig template

so that I can use the codes to underline etc., and finally cut the paper, from inside the twig template.

I'm sure this would involve a twig extension to create an additional filter, which I know how to make, I just don't know WHAT EXACTLY it should do or how to go about the conversion from twig to escape code which would be picked up by fwrite

I've been looking for 2 days, and I really can't seem to figure this out on my own, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its alive, just the syntax for the `getFilters()` was slightly different:

```
public function getGlobals()
{
    return [
        'ticket_cut' => chr(hexdec('1B')).chr(hexdec('69'))
    ];
}




public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFilter('ticketBold', array($this, 'ticketBold')),
    );
}



public function ticketBold($string)
{

   return chr(hexdec('1B')).chr(hexdec('45'))."1".$string.chr(hexdec('1B')).chr(hexdec('45'))."0";

}
```

Thx for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Oh I need to update my Twig extension's to use the Twig_SimpleFilter... sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Configure your twig extension:

```
services:
    your.twig.pos_printer_extension:
        class: Your\CustomBundle\Twig\POSPrinterExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Create your extension:

```
<?php

namespace Your\CustomBundle\Twig;

class POSPrinterExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getGlobals()
    {
        return [
            'some_constant' => chr(hexdec('0A'))
        ];
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return [
            'bold' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'bold')
        ];
    }

    public function bold($text)
    {
        return chr(hexdec('0B')) . $text . chr(hexdec('0A'));
    }
}
```

And finally use it in your twig templates:

```
{{ some_constant }}

{{ receipt.amount | bold }}
```

You can apply filters to an [entire block](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/filter.html) too:

```
{% filter bold %}
    Dear {{ name }},
{% endfilter %}
```

Obviously I don't know the correct escaped chars but you got the idea right?

**UPDATE** (I'm writing this to avoid downvotes)

My example is using `Twig_Filter_Method` which is deprecated since 1.12 (to be removed in 2.0), you should be using `Twig_SimpleFilter` instead.

Comment: awsome, i will be testing this out today. i'll update this as soon as i can .   thx in advance.